# Can I make a DIY Cloud server for windows?

Tags: linux, windows, cloud, multiple-users

My old parents have been hacked/virus-ed for the nth time.

I have an old HP server.

I thought of rebuilding it with VMWare (free version) or Oracle virtualbox and having them use windows in a controlled environment.  I would back it up and patch it, etc.  Maybe they RDC to my server.

I assume I would need a Windows server license to allow multiple connections.  (I could also use it for myself to host Plex media server.)

At a 10,000 foot level, is this possible or just a technology quagmire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super User SE might be a better place for this.

Anyway: Are they using it for anything windows-specific? My parents used to use my Linux-based computer for web browsing, now they use an Android tablet for the same. Running a virtualised Windows on top of the former could've been an alternative. Also, backing up and rolling back is easier if you use virtualisation, just use something else for permanent data storage. Maybe a remote storage with backup and rollback (for ransomware) either your own infrastucture or in the cloud. (like syncthing, owncloud, etc.)

I'm assuming here they don't have trade secrets or plans of a home-built nuclear plant or anything that kind.